# Nginx rule to redirect specific https link only

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy

I have configured nginx as reverse proxy tool. I have come across a problem which I have not been able to deal with. Following are the rules I have set in my .conf file.

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name rp.mydomain.com;
        return 301 https://$host/myapp1/;
        location / {
        proxy_pass <local ip address>;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect http://$host https://$host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
   server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  rp.mydomain.com;
        location / {
        proxy_pass <local ip address>;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
}
    }
```

My application resides on /myapp1/ . The reason why I am not writing /myapp1/ in the proxy_pass [I tried] is because the redirection is not working properly WHEN I try to login on the page. I get the error page not found.

But after this rule in listen 80 block, return 301 `https://$host/myapp1/;`  its working like charm, but only if I go open the http page.

When I open the link, `rp.mydomain.com`. The redirection is working perfectly and the application works fine too. The http request is redirected to https and I can log in through my app.

But, when I go through `https://rp.mydomain.com`, I end up at the blank page of `<local ip address>`, because of the `proxy_pass` rule in `listen 443`.

My requirement is whenever the specific request of the page is generated, which is, `https://rp.mydomain.com`, its redirected to `https://rp.mydomain.com/myapp1/` (like when it does when the user accesses the page through `http://rp.mydomain.com`) but the other requests, like `https://rp.mydomain.com/myapp1/` or `https://rp.mydomain.com/myapp1/profile` [etc etc] are not affected.

Just one specific page `https://rp.mydomain.com` gets redirected automatically.

Is it possible to do so? Please help me in this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name rp.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  rp.mydomain.com;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /myapp1/ last;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass <local ip address>;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
}
```

The `location = /` block has been added to create the mapping from `/` to `/myapp1/`. To change the URL in the browser, use `permanent` instead of `last`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

You will need to add additional `proxy_redirect` statements to prevent your *local ip address* leaking out when the application performs a redirect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

It is assumed that your SSL certificates are defined in an outer block and inherited.